# What does the following code snippet mean?

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){
              //some code
          },function(){
               // some code
   }();
</script>
```

Does it simply mean, executing multiple functions on `window.onload` event?

Comment: I didn't know this, but it works in reverse. http://output.jsbin.com/pizecucaso

Comment: I wanted to know how this code work, will it fire both functions on window.onload?

Comment: Why don't you create a [test case](https://jsfiddle.net/en708h1u/) and find out what happens ..?

Comment: You can use the comma to seperate expressions e.g. `a=b, c=d`, so actually its just a regular `=` followed by an IIFE

Comment: @teemu, yes i just created a test case. Both functions will execute in reverse order on load. Thank you

Comment: @user3377819: No, only one of them executes on load. The first one that executes is doing so before the page is fully loaded.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, in this specific example the code would behave exactly the same way if the comma was replaced by a semicolon. That might make it easier to understand. EDIT: Nevermind, it would actually create a syntax error because the IIFE needs to be wrapped in parentheses. But in theory, it's still similar if you picture it that way.

Answer (score 1):

> Does it simply meant, executing multiple functions on window.onload
>   event?

Only one function will get executed on `window.onload` event.

**See why:**

There're two operators of importance to us here: `=` and `,`:

```
window.onload = function1(){ }, function2(){ }()
```

However, since `=` operator takes precedence over `,` operator, the left side of `,` becomes, this:

```
window.onload = function1(){ ... }
```

and not this:

```
function1(){ ... }
```

Which is why `function1` gets assigned to `window.onload` and not `function2`.

Then the right side of the `,` operator runs, i.e. `function2` - and since it's an IIFE it gets invoked there on the spot, but its return value is not stored anywhere.

*For precedence rules see*: [operator associativity & precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence).

**To sum up the order of execution:**

1. function1 is passed (not executed) to window.onload
2. function2 gets executed
3. ... some time later, when the document is done loading, it executes function1

Comment: Yes, but that's a matter of how the operators' precedence are interpreted given that their precedence is equal. In other words, it's effectively rewritten as though you had added parens, like this:  `(a = (b = 5))`, whereas if it had been *left associative*, it would be `((a = b) = 5)`. But the evaluation is still left to right; the `a` binding is evaluated first, then its assignment is performed, where `b` is evaluated and its assignment takes place, giving `b` the value `5`, which becomes the return value of the inner `()`, giving `a` the same value.

Comment: To better test it, you can invoke `window.onload()` *inside* the IIFE. If the assignment hadn't taken place yet, then `.onload` would be `null`, causing an error. Here's a demo https://jsfiddle.net/hnywfbqx/

Comment: *"What that means is that the right most function gets evaluated first"* No, that's not what *"Assignment operators are right-associative"* means. How the assignment operator works is rather irrelevant here. Only its precedence over the comma operator is what's important in this case.

Comment: @rockstar I already tested it using `console.log(window.onload);`. Anyway thanks for the breakdown.

Comment: Good description. +1 If I was to be super pedantic, I'd point out that there are a couple more operators too (the `.` member access and `()` function call), whose precedence need to be considered, but I think your answer drives the main point home.

Comment: Changed it to: "There're two operators of importance to us here"

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't mean it'll be executing multiple functions. If you want to achieve that do it like this ([source](https://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3724571/Using-Multiple-JavaScript-Onload-Functions.htm)):

```
function func1() {
    //some code
}

function func2() {
    //some code
}

window.onload = function(){
    func1();
    func2();
};
```

Using parenthesis `()` after function means that you execute this function right away, so you don't wanna use it.

Comma you showed in your example simply does nothing in this case.

You just seperate it. You bind your first function to onload event, and then execute annonymus function (because you use parenthesis `()`)

Maybe proper formatting will help you see it more clearly:

```
window.onload = function(){
    //some code
},

function(){
    // some code
}();
```

Comment: *"If you want to accive that you simply do it one more time:"* Nope.

Comment: Why, no. I would do it in such a way that the multiple functions will actually be executed.

Comment: *"Comma u showed in your example simply does nothing."* That's not quite right. The comma operator does something.

Comment: "If you want to accive that you simply do it one more time:" Nope. - Yeah, you're right, my bad.

Comment: Even the source link you provided is telling you it won't work. See, it's not great to start off with an answer that claims the question is "terrible" when the answer itself is making a beginner's mistake.

Comment: @FelixKling Is the comma in the snippet the comma operator? I mean if it was, the result of the IIFE should become to the value of `onload`, but it isn't, the first function expression is set to onload handler instead.

Comment: I meant the syntax was terrible. I editet my mistakes. Well, english is my second language and so I sometimes write not what I mean. I'm sorry for that :)

Comment: @Teemu: The `=` has higher precedence than the `,`, so it's `((x = "foo"), "bar")`

Comment: @rockstar Indeed, though that makes OP's example even more interesting, since literals instead of function expressions are firing a syntax error ...

Comment: @Teemu: Except that it is a function expression. Because the `,` is an operator, it forces the evaluation of the `function` syntax to be a function expression. It would only be a syntax error if one of the comma's operands was unable to be seen as an expression, like `x = "foo", if (true) {}`

Comment: @rockstar Yep, and no syntax errors if literals are used (I tumbled with var in my test). Wrapping right-side into parenthesis will evaluate comma operator as expected, i.e. the first function is never executed, and the second function will be run before onload, and onload handler will not be assigned.

Comment: @Teemu: The `onload` handler is assigned with the OP's original code, and will be invoked when the page is loaded. You don't need parentheses on the right. It doesn't matter if it's a function literal, it will be interpreted as an expression, not a declaration. If you tested in jsFiddle, make sure you have a "nowrap" setting chosen. If it's the "onLoad" setting, then the handler won't fire because that event has already passed.

Comment: ...[here's the demo](https://jsfiddle.net/hnywfbqx/) I posted in another comment. You'll see the `onload` invoked twice. Once when I manually invoked it in the IIFE, and once when the page is fully loaded.

Comment: @rockstar The link to my original testing fiddle is in the comment thread of the question. It is correctly set. I was just confused of the operator precedence in this particular case (the case in the original post).

Comment: @Teemu: Ah yeah, I didn't see your demo. I was confused about the precedence at first too. I intuitively expected to see the return value of the second function assigned to the `.onload`, but then realized that the `=` would be first grouped with its left and right sides.

Comment: @rockstar That's exactly what I expected to happen too. Got a lesson here, not that the structure would be useful, but it helps my future debugging in case of accidentally writing something like that.

Answer (score 0):

the `function(){}()` (let's call it **f1**) makes use of a syntax that means "execute me as soon as the javascript is loaded".

In this case as soon as entire script in the  tag is loaded the **f1** is executed.

After that as soon as the windows.load event is triggered, the onload associated function is called.